# Overloading operators in PhoneCall class

Tags: c++, beginner, operator-overloading

I am trying to understand the concepts of `friend` functions, overloaded operators, and inheritance in C++. I am very confused on the specifics used for coding, since I am fairly new in programming, and working in the Visual Studio C++ environment in writing code.

The following is the project details for writing a program in Visual Studio C++:

> Design a `PhoneCall` class that holds a phone number to which a call
>   is placed, the length of the call in minutes, and the rate charged per
>   minute. Overload extraction and insertion operators for the class. In
>   this program, overload the `==` operator to compare two `PhoneCall`s.
>   Consider one `PhoneCall` to be equal to another if both calls are
>   placed to the same number. Also, create a `main()` function that allows
>   you to enter ten `PhoneCall`s into an array. If a `PhoneCall` has
>   already been placed to a number, do not allow a second `PhoneCall` to
>   the same number.

I really need some feedback on the following code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 

using namespace std; 

class PhoneCall { 
private: 
    string phonenumber; 
    double perminuterate; 
    double calldurationminutes; 
public: 
    bool operator==( const PhoneCall &n ) const; 
    friend ostream & operator<<( ostream &f, const PhoneCall &n ); 
    friend istream & operator>>( istream &f, PhoneCall &n ); 
 }; 
 bool PhoneCall::operator==( const PhoneCall &n ) const { 
    return phonenumber == n.phonenumber; 
 }; 
 ostream & operator<<( ostream &f, const PhoneCall &n ) { 
    f << "Phone number: " << n.phonenumber << 
         ", Duration: " << n.calldurationminutes << 
         " minutes, Rate: " << n.perminuterate << endl; 
 return f; 
 } 
 istream & operator>>( istream &f, PhoneCall &n ) { 
 f >> n.phonenumber; 
 f >> n.calldurationminutes; 
 f >> n.perminuterate; 
 return f; 
 } 

int main( ) { 
 PhoneCall a[10]; 
 cout << "Enter 10 phone numbers, duration in minutes, and the per-minute rates." << 
     endl << "Separate each with a space and then hit enter to complete it." << endl; 
 for ( int i= 0; i < 10; ) { 
     cin >> a[i]; 
     int j; 
     for ( j= 0; j < i; ++j ) 
         if ( a[i] == a[j] ) { 
             cout << "Duplicate number information ignored. Try again." << endl; 
             break; 
         } 
     if ( j == i ) ++i; 
 } 
 for ( int i= 0; i < 10; ++i ) 
     cout << a[i];

 system("pause");
 return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: Your indentation is very inconsistent.  Four spaces is preferred.  One space in `main()` is a little strange.

Answer (score 5):

```
using namespace std;
```

This is generally frowned upon, especially at the "global" level like this. Since you don't know what names might be defined inside `namespace std`, this has the potential to create conflicts with your code.

```
class PhoneCall { 
private:
```

Although it's harmless, the `private:` here is redundant--members of a `class` are private by default.

```
    string phonenumber; 
    double perminuterate; 
    double calldurationminutes;
```

I think I'd rename these to something like:

```
string phone_number;
double per_minute_rate;
double call_duration_minutes;
```

If *at all* possible, I'd use an `std::vector` instead of a "raw" array, so this:

```
 PhoneCall a[10];
```

...would turn into something like:

```
std::vector<PhoneCall> a(10);
```

`std::endl` is drastically overused. I'd generally just use `'\n';`. `endl` also flushes the file's buffer, which you rarely want. When you read/write `cin` and `cout`, flushes are done automatically between writing and reading anyway.

```
 cout << "Enter 10 phone numbers, duration in minutes, and the per-minute rates." << 
     endl << "Separate each with a space and then hit enter to complete it." << endl; 
 for ( int i= 0; i < 10; ) { 
     cin >> a[i]; 
     int j; 
     for ( j= 0; j < i; ++j ) 
         if ( a[i] == a[j] ) { 
             cout << "Duplicate number information ignored. Try again." << endl; 
             break; 
         } 
     if ( j == i ) ++i; 
 }
```

You might want to use `std::find` to find whether the array already contains an instance of a particular phone number. This could simplify your logic quite a bit.

When you print out your phone call objects:

```
 for ( int i= 0; i < 10; ++i ) 
     cout << a[i];
```

...you traditionally want to only print out the data itself in your `operator<<`, and leave any final new-line to separate one object from the next to be printed somewhere else (like right here).

```
 system("pause");
```

I'd avoid this, and use something like:

```
std::cout << "Press return to quit."
char ch;
std::cin.get(ch);
```

Comment: Everything he said. The only difference is that I woudl use camel case notation for variable names: `calldurationminutes` => `callDurationMinutes`;

Comment: How about `std::cin.ignore();` instead of `char ch; std::cin.get(ch);`?

Answer (score 4):

Apart from Jerry's remarks, I would also provide an **`operator!=`** to go along with `operator==` (implementing the former in terms of the latter to avoid code duplication),  and make both operators **non-member `friend`** functions.

One advantage is that non-member functions treat left/right arguments symmetrically and avoid tricky argument conversion ambiguities when you have single-argument constructors (not the case in this example, but it's a good habit to get into).

If you have to overload other operators, there is even a [**Boost.Operators**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) library to help you do this automatically if you overload (overkill for this example, though).

Finally, I prefer writing `ArgType const& argname` because `const` applies right-to-left.

```
class PhoneCall 
{ 
public:
//....
    friend bool operator==(PhoneCall const& L, PhoneCall const& R)
    {
        return L.phone_number == R.phone_number;  
    }

    friend bool operator!=(PhoneCall const& L, PhoneCall const& R)
    {
        return !(L == R);
    }         
 };
```

Further reading: [**the Operator Overloading Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).